# How to the maximum variable length of Red Hat Business Central?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, redhat, bpmn

I was using Red Hat Business Central version 7.48.0.Final. When I try to change a variable value of a process instance to a string with more than 255 characters, It just get truncate the string to the first 255 characters. If I am not mistaken, this is caused because Business Central has the default maximum variable length of 255.

How can I increase the maximum variable length?

Answer (score 0):

In installation folder find standalone.xml and add

`

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="org.jbpm.var.log.length" value="20000"/>
</system-properties
```

`

More: https://dzone.com/articles/increase-the-default-process-variable-size-in-jbpm